# in c# how would one escape a break in quotes

Tags: c#, mysql, escaping

i am trying to database some files on my computer with mysql in c#, its having an issue with VALUES ('drum'n'bass')

Answer (score 5):

You use a backslash - `\'` to escape a single quote:

```
VALUES ('drum\'n\'bass')
```

You should however be using prepared statements and not build SQL strings yourself.

Comment: I agree. But if you do want to create SQL manually, you should at least use `string.Format()` to deal with the quotes.

Comment: since C# is given, we can probably assume that all this is within a string (also, since the above is not valid C# code, as single quote denotes char). In that case, we need the double backslash, because the single quote is not an escapable character within a string. we want to *actually add a backslash* to the string, that is being passed to mysql. *that's* where it'll be used to escape: `string sql = "... VALUES('drum\\'n\\'bass')"`

Comment: @David - I am assuming this error is occurring on the SQL server.

Comment: well yes, I'm guessing that's very likely where the error occurs, but since C# is thrown into the mix, I'm also guessing that the SQL string is *generated* by C#, and then you are very much right that OP wants a string that *ends up* like in your example. I was only going into detail as to how such a string is achieved which may or may not have been obvious to OP. This might be a non-issue tho as you've already raised the more important point of not putting yourself in a situation where you need to worry about this in the first place =)

Answer (score 0):

If you for some reason need to escape the strings yourself instead of using a parameterised query, you need to escape both backslashes and apostrophes for a literal string in MySQL:

```
value = value.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace("'", @"\'");
```

This is important, if you don't escape the strings correctly, the query is wide open for SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Just to reiterate, you shouldn't be doing this yourself.

Use parameterised queries:

[MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlparameter)

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.wiredworx.co.uk/website-and-seo/c-tutorials-and-tips-visual-studio/save-apostrophe-to-a-mysql-database-using-c/

```
private string escapeChar(string strToEsc)

{    
    if (strToEsc.IndexOf("'") > -1)
    {
        strToEsc = strToEsc.Replace("'", @"'");
    }

    if (strToEsc.IndexOf("’") > -1)
    {
        strToEsc = strToEsc.Replace("’", @"’");
    }

    if (strToEsc.IndexOf("‘") > -1)
    {
        strToEsc = strToEsc.Replace("‘", @"‘");

    }

    return strToEsc;
}
```